# add space from left side for text in div itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating pdf from html string. I am using itextsharp. 
I have div in that i am adding string with p tag and i want to leave space from left side.

```
<div style="margin-left:50px;">
<p>1 - Test1</p>
<p>2 - Test2</p>
<p>3 - Test3</p>
<p>4 - Test4</p>
<p>5 - Test5</p>
</div>
```

I tried with margin-left, \t but nothing is getting applied.

Comment: I think some of your question is missing.

Comment: Are you using `HTMLWorker` or `XmlWorker` for translating from HTML markup to PDF commands? I don't know if this list is still current but according to it `margin` is not supported on a `<div>`. http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm

Comment: I am using XmlWorker.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to add space using **padding-left**.